# Get HTML from a hidden portion of code in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yql

The title is a little confusing so let me explain better what the problem I'm having is.

I need to extract a certain portion of HTML out of a page. This portion of code is inside of a div that "on page load" is hidden by default. You have to click on that div in order to make that portion of code appear.

Now, I need to get this code with a javascript/jquery script with either pure AJAX request to the page or YQL but the problem is: How do I "simulate" the click on that div?

How can I make that div toggle just with the code in order to access the code inside of it?

By the way, the request is from the same domain so there's no problem with cross-domain AJAX.

Thank you!

Comment: How does the ajax come into it? Have you tried $("#div").click();

Comment: I use AJAX because the request is from another page within the same domain. Now I know I can use .click event but is that doable cross-page before an AJAX request? I'd basically need from page1.html load a hidden div inside of page2.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery .click

```
$("#Id_Of_the_Div_you_want_to_click").click();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers! But is that doable when in an AJAX request? I mean, I'm requesting that portion's code from another page so I'd need to simulate the click from that page and then proceed with the request. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding is if you do 
`$('#hiddenElementID').html()` will return the contents of it or even `$('#hiddenElementID').text()` if its hidden or not.

But if you really must simulate a click then do `$('#hiddenElementID').click()`

And to toggle use your own function and do `$('#hiddenElementID').hide()`  and `$('#hiddenElementID').show()`

Or use `$('#hiddenElementID').toggle()`

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try on Ajax `success:event`

```
function(data){
   //Convert Data to jQuery Object
   var element = $(data);
   element.find('#HiddenDiv').show();
}
```

Because manipulating DOM Element's triggering Fake Event's is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate click events like so:

```
$("#div").click()
```

It sounds to me like you're trying to get data from another page. The data is compiled after a click event. You could try the following:

- AJAX get the page with the required data
- Render the page into a hidded `iframe` within your page
- Simulate click events on the nested page to produce data
- Access the bits you want and discard the `iframe` contents.

If I get some time later I'll try it out for myself and see if it can be done.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! But is that doable when in an AJAX request? I mean, I'm requesting that portion's code from another page so I'd need to simulate the click from that page and then proceed with the request. Is that possible?

Comment: Just because it's hidden doesn't mean you shouldn't be able to get the HTML out of it. You probably don't even need to simulate a click.

Comment: Actually I do because when looking up the code in the page with both Firebug and Chrome's dev tools it doesn't show up until I click. It's just an empty div.

Comment: @waivy in that case there is some other behaviour that the page is performing which you will need to simulate. If the click event on the second page is itself performing an ajax request to get the div content then you're set - you just need to call that second resource.

Comment: Don't know if it performs an ajax request itself but I see that the tr has an onclick attribute that calls a function which is probably what expands the div. Inside of it there's another div handled the exact same way with another onclick attribute that expands even more the div giving more detailed information, which I need to get.